# C#.Net Windows Message to Delphi

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, windows-messages

I'm having a trouble with Windows Messages between a c# app and delphi app.

I did some examples with c# to c# and delphi to delphi but I cannot c# to delphi

Here is my related c# app which is WM sender codes

```
    void Game1_Exiting(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] Processes = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach(Process p in Processes)
            if(p.ProcessName == Statics.MainAppProcessName)
                SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_TOOTHUI, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);


    }

    private const int WM_TOOTHUI = 0xAAAA;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Here is my related delphi app which is WM reciever codes

```
    const
      WM_TOOTHUI = 43690;
    type
      private
        MsgHandlerHWND : HWND;
        procedure WndMethod(var Msg: TMessage);

    procedure TForm1.WndMethod(var Msg: TMessage);
    begin
      if Msg.Msg = WM_TOOTHUI then
      begin
        Caption := 'Message Recieved';
      end;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      MsgHandlerHWND := AllocateHWnd(WndMethod);
    end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You are sending the message to the main window handle. That's the handle of the instance of `TForm1`. But your window procedure is attached to a different window handle, the window handled created by your call to `AllocateHWnd`.

A simple fix would be to override `WndProc` in `TForm1` rather than using `AllocateHWnd`.

```
// in your class declaration:
procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;

// the corresponding implementation:
procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Msg.Msg = WM_TOOTHUI then
  begin
    Caption := 'Message Recieved';
  end; 
  inherited;
end;
```

Or as Mason says, you can use the special message handling syntax of Delphi:

```
// in your class declaration:
procedure WMToothUI(var Message: TMessage); message WM_TOOTHUI;

// the corresponding implementation:
procedure TForm1.WMToothUI(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Caption := 'Message Recieved';
end;
```

It's also possible that `p.MainWindowHandle` is not even the handle to your main window. If you are using an older version of Delphi then `p.MainWindowHandle` may locate the application's handle, `Application.Handle`. In which case you will need `FindWindow` or `EnumWindows` in your C# code to locate the desired window.

Also, your code would be clearer if you declared the message constant using hex in Delphi:

```
WM_TOOTHUI = $AAAA;
```

Comment: Or, even simpler than that, create a `message` method on TForm1 that handles `WM_TOOTHUI`. No `WndProc` rewriting needed!

Comment: @David Heffernan I tried your first advice but it recieving some messages except my WM_TOOTHUI message

Comment: That's to be expected. If you want to send the message to the main window then expect lots of other messages to arrive also.

Comment: But my WM_TOOTHUI message is not comming, and I tried Mason Wheeler's too

Comment: Is the handle of the `TForm1` instance the same as the handle that your C# program is sending the message to? If so, then it will arrive. If not then, well, it won't.

Comment: In c# debug mode I placed a breakpoint on SendMessage(); func. and it stopped there, because there is one process with name 'Project2' which is my delphi app's name.When delphi project is not running, it doesn't stop there. Also I tried on c# side p.handle and p.MainWindowHandle...

Comment: I saw a property called HandleCount in process object. Is there many Handles does one application has? If so how can I get the right handle?

Comment: I ask again. Is the handle that you send the message to the same as the handle of the Delphi form? One possible failure mode is that you are sending it to the Delphi Application.Handle. You might need to be more careful in how you get the handle to make sure you get the right one. Another possible failure mode is that your Delphi IDE runs as admin.

Comment: First of all check whether your two handles match. If not, you need FindWindow or EnumWindows. If they do match your message is being blocked by UIPI. Stop running your Delphi app elevated.

Comment: Yes, the FindWindow and FindWindowEx functions worked. Thank you David.